# list named argument in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have have the following strings

```
s1 = "/url/{part}"
s2 = "/url/{code}"
```

How can I extract the named arguments from the above strings, and get `part` and `code`?

Comment: A regular expression that matches everything from `{` to `}` would be a simple way to do it.

Comment: Just for fun, see https://repl.it/@JustinEzequiel/EnchantingUpbeatLinuxpc for an alternative that uses `str.format` and catches the `KeyError`. Not recommended for production use.